# How to verify the correctness of a kernel upgrade before performing the final reboot

Tags: kernel, update

I remotely manage a couple of raspberry-pi's as vpn servers using ssl over openvpn.

One of these pi's is becoming problematic: it recently somehow gets misconfigured after almost every raspberrypi-kernel or -bootloader upgrade.

Since the problem until now happened using Stretch, I was hoping that a fresh install of Buster on another sd card would fix it, but unfortunately, already the first (remote) upgrade after the fresh install failed similarly.

The upgrade is performed on a Raspberry Pi 2 Model B using the normal apt-get upgrade procedure

There were no related errors/warnings reported on screen during the upgrade

**Before** the reboot I perform the following checks:

```
debsums -c raspberrypi-kernel
debsums -c raspberrypi-bootloader
check for errors in /var/log/apt/term.log

check dates and md5sums in /boot
check dates and md5sums in /boot/overlays
check dates and md5sums in /var/cache/apt/archives/raspberrypi-*
```

and everything is fine

Note: I get the dates and md5sums from a similarly installed pi

The upgrade was supposed to bring the kernel from **4.19.58** to **4.19.66**

**After** the reboot however,`uname -a` still returns **4.19.58**

This preventing the openvpn server from starting up properly, and consequently I have to go through several hoops to get access to the problem pi over ssl (the ssl server fortunately still starts up)

The `/lib/modules` folder contains the (new) **4.19.66** subfolders

The `md5sums` of some files in `/boot` and `/boot/overlays` do not match any more

and running `debsums` on `raspberrypi-(bootloader kernel)` shows problems

It happens on both on Stretch and Buster, and I have used another sd card for the Buster installation. However, as far as I know, all 'code' comes from the sd card and nothing is written to the board...

Is there more that I could check **before** the reboot to **predict** problems?

Any hints on how to proceed would be welcome.

Comment: If you've installed with `apt upgrade` it has done all the checking you need. Just `sudo reboot` is needed for the final confirmation.

Comment: Is there a difference between apt and apt-get with respect to this checking? I have been using apt-get so far.

Comment: `apt-get` is for scripting, `apt` is for command line. The both drive dpkg which does the work.

Answer (score 2):

Although not a direct answer to this question, this problem has been solved and the answer may help other users having problems with kernel and/or bootloader upgrades.

In this specific case, the problem was caused by an additional USB card reader inserted into one of the free USB ports of the remote Pi, containing a 'perfect' clone of the master SD card from which the Pi boots.

Being a 'perfect' clone, the **UUID**'s of the partitions on the **master** SD card and the partitions on the **cloned** SD card were **identical**. This 'confused' the boot process, which, after booting from the master SD card, mounted the **boot** partition of the **cloned** SD card on **/boot**, while the **root** partition of the **master** SD card was mounted on '**/**'.

During an upgrade of raspberrypi-kernel and bootloader, the boot partition on the cloned SD card would get updated instead of the boot partition of the master SD card.

For more information see: [How does the pi select the device to boot from?](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=28&t=254754)

In my case, I worked around the issue by **not** using the **UUID**'s as partition identifiers, but instead using the **partition names** (**/dev/mmcblk0p1** and **/dev/mmcblk0p2**) as identifiers in **/etc/fstab** and **/boot/cmdline.txt**

It would also have been also possible to simply change the UUID's of the cloned SD card. Note however, that the UUID's to be used as identifiers are the **partition UUID**'s, which can be displayed using: **lsblk -o name,partuuid**

Comment: And what is the solution? Unplug the card reader?

Comment: That would also have been an option, yes. If you follow the link in the answer, several options are proposed, but I have updated the answer with the path I took to work around the issue. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you for completing the answer. I haven't followed the link because providing only a link to understand an answer isn't considered to be a good answer ;-)